# GCC Memory Overload when Linking

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, clang

Disclaimer: Please don't mock my machine. It's all I have and can afford at this point in time.

```
Legacy Bios Dell Mobo
Athlon II X4 640 Processor
4Gb DDR3 Ram
500Gb HHD
```

Hello World! I have been trying to compile llvm/clang-tools for the past week and a half using cmake/ninja with gcc or a the default version of clang from the base repository.

Every time I try, they compiler crashes and stubbornly I start again.  At first I kept repartitioning and reinstalling Ubuntu to the point where I was adding 12Gb of swap partition, and yet I had an unstable system and a compiler that wouldn't get the job done.

I stopped right there, and decided I should go as light as I knew possible on the OS and try again (thinking it would make for a more stable system with less bloat).  I installed Arch Linux with a minimal build and a dynamic swap file. Without the thought of giving up, I kept on compiling. Now I still get the same memory overload, but the OS is able to manage it and kick out the process with out me doing a hard reboot.  I consider that a step in the right direction.

Coming from Visual Studio, I am a virgin to compiler flags.

This is my build:

Default to ccache.

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ../llvm
$ ln -s $PWD/compile_commands.json ../llvm
$ ninja -j2 check-all
```

Still have the memory overload on single threaded "$ make .....".

Besides spending the $20 to fill out the the last 2 slots of ram (which my wife did give me permission to do for my birthday), what can a poor guy like me do to get access to this valuable tool and go back to compiling my own C++ code?

Comment: Why do you need to compile Clang yourself?  Given your limited resources wouldn't it make sense to use a build made by someone else?

Comment: Building non-trivial compilers and other developer's tools - and llvm/clang or gcc would both qualify as non-trivial - tends to consume a lot of memory.

Comment: 1) add more swap. 2) build with `-j1` to not run multiple compilers in parallel. 3) wait (quite a while).

Comment: From what I recall the default build type for `llvm` is `debug`.  That could require a *lot* of extra memory/swap over a `release` build.  If that's the case try setting the build type to `release` using `cmake`.

Comment: You can also reduce the compilation time by only targetting your CPU architecture - if you don't want a cross-compiler - instead of all of the supported ones. Use `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepackaged versions of clang/llvm if you really need the latest and greatest (do you?). Have a look here for Arch : https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/clang-svn/ .

Comment: Very cool.  I will have to update my machine. I ended up putting the precompiled binaries off of LLVM's website. It was good for -v 6.0.0 on an arch machine.  Really like the AUR. This move from windows to linux has really made my head explode, but it seems to be for the better.  On a Windows machine using VS, it just click or a key press to build a project.  Deciding to use a text editor instead of a ide was one of the best decisions I made, since it is teaching me more on the build process.  Just wanted to add that.